# Python expects indent inside raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can't find anything specifically for my problem. Python expects an indent block literally inside of the raw_input.

```
relations = 0
firstNumber = 0
secondNumber = 0
def additionProblem(x, y):
    answer = x + y
    return answer
def askingTheNumbers(self):
    firstNumber = int(raw_input("What is the first number?"))
    secondNumber = int(raw_input("What is the second number?"))
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now
while True:
    firstResponse = raw_input("Hi! I am a really bad AI created by none other than (names removed for privacy. How was your day?")
while True:
    if firstResponse.lower() in ['good', 'great', 'amazing'] and relations == 0:
    artificialResponse = raw_input("Wow! That's great! I can do very limited things right now. All I'm programmed to do is math and the time.")
        relations = 1
    if relations == 1:
        artificialResponse = raw_input("Would you like me to do anything else?")
    if artificialResponse.lower() in [time]:
        whatTimeIsIt = raw_input("Would you like to know the year, month, day, hour, minute, second, or microsecond? You can choose multiple if you want.")
        if whatTimeIsIt.lower() in ['year']:
            print "Current year: %d" % now.year
        if whatTimeIsIt.lower() in ['month']:
            print "Current month: %d" % now.month
        if whatTimeIsIt.lower() in ['day']:
            print "Current day: %d" % now.day
        if whatTimeIsIt.lower() in ['hour']:
            print "Current hour: %d" % now.hour
        if whatTimeIsIt.lower() in ['minute']:
            print "Current minute: %d" % now.minute
        if whatTimeIsIt.lower() in ['second']:
            print "Current minute: %d" % now.second
        if whatTimeIsIt.lower() in ['microsecond']:
            print "Current microsecond (though I don't know why you care): %d" % now.microsecond
    elif artificialResponse.lower() in ['math']:
        mathProblem = raw_input("Great! Would you like me to do addition, multiplication, division, or multiplication?")
        if mathProblem.lower() in ['addition']:
            askingTheNumbers(pass)
            additionAnswer = additionProblem(firstNumber, secondNumber)
            print "The answer is", additionAnswer
```

On line 16, it expects the program to have an indent block, but I have absolutely no idea why that would be. This is also my first real project in python, so tell me if you see anything that could be improved on.

Comment: It doesn't want an indent *in* that function.  That whole line needs to be indented.  Put four spaces at the beginning of the line, and watch what happens.  Magic!

Comment: That was the problem XD can't believe I didn't notice that earlier. Thanks!

Comment: All you need to do is indent line 16 like Python tells you.  Reading the Traceback errors in Python is a really great way to debug Python.

Comment: Please do some research (like reading the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html)) before posting a question.

Comment: I'm not sure the interpreter would ever reach that line though give the `while True:` line above it

Comment: It doesn't want the line to "have" an indented block; it wants the line to *be part of* the indented block that it's expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and received the error on line 10 not line 16.  Line 10 required indentation.  I fixed this, ran the code, and received an error on line 33.  You cannot use the `pass` reserved word as an argument to a function.  A function invocation with no arguments is simply an empty argument list `()`.  I ran your program after fixing this error and it begins executing with the message:

`Hi! I am a really bad AI created by none other than (names removed for privacy. How was your day?`

Assuming this is what you expect, all should be well with the syntax errors.  But probably not the semantic ones.  I assume you did not intend to have a one line infinite loop but have the rest of the code afterward be part of that loop.

As they say, the remainder is left as an exercise to the student.